# Error while returning DataSet from XML Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services

I have created Windows Application that needs to get data from SQL Server. In order to do that easy I also have XML Web Service and here is the code that I use to return DataSet:

```
[WebMethod]
public DataSet GetDataSet(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
    {
        cmd.Connection = Conn;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        try
        {
            //Conn.Open();
            using (DataSet DS = new DataSet())
            {
                da.Fill(DS);
                return DS;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return (new DataSet());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (da != null)
            {
                da.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And when I want to Add my Web Service into my Win Application Project it gives the following Error:

> Cannot serialize member System.ComponentModel.Component.Site of type System.ComponentModel.ISite because it is an interface

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read the following article as I don't think you can Serialise an Interface object :-

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/bac96f79-82cd-4fef-a748-2a85370a8510/

Answer (score 1):

SqlCommand cannot be serialized, so you will need to instantiate in the function.

```
 [WebMethod]
 public DataSet GetDataSet()
 {
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
 using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
 {
    cmd.Connection = Conn;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    try
    {
        //Conn.Open();
        using (DataSet DS = new DataSet())
        {
            da.Fill(DS);
            return DS;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return (new DataSet());
    }
    finally
    {
        if (da != null)
        {
            da.Dispose();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So what does this answer? What is different than the code in question? I get your point but it needs a little bit explanation.

Comment: SqlCommand cannot be serialized. Therefore you can't send in parameter.

Comment: @L.B Thanks for the response. But the reason I wanted to send parameter is in 1 Form I call 4 or 5 SQL Commands and I would like to use ready DataSet to easily send CommandText with parameters and get the table. Because I don't want to create Connection each time.

Comment: Because I want to use this DataSet in all my Project Forms where I need to connect to DB to get data.

Comment: @Shohin Answer is from Muhammad Hussain, not from me.

Comment: Oops Sorry. @MuhammadHussain - so my goal is to use 1 public DataSet with ready connection and use it in any Forms to get Data From DB. Is there any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Comment: @Shohin --You can keep this dataset in a session variable and then use it from anywhere in your application.